# Как передать юзеру заголовок с именем файла с пробелом и русскими символами?

Tags: php

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".urlencode("Огого! Ого")."");
```

Итог: крякозябры

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename("Огого! ого")."");
```

Итог: в ответе "!"

Comment: Взять в кавычки?

Comment: Вы задали вопрос который давно многих волнует, но ответа на него практически нет. Есть http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2184.html в котором написано о формате.

Comment: Там написано что можно использовать US-ASCII. Остальные символы надо хитро преобразовывать. В PHP функции для этого нет. Вроде самая близкая rawurlencode, но немного не то.

Comment: http://test.greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/